# HTML onclick Event Attribute not work phone

Tags: jquery, html, ios, events, onclick

I'm trying to show different links in the same Iframe using a onclick Event, It's run on computers but not on phones. I know it's something like 'touchstart click' in jquery but in the tag I don't know how to make that.

```
<a class="link" href="project-url"
   onclick="document.getElementById('project_iframe').src=this.href; return false;">
   <h3>title</h3>
</a>

<iframe id="project_iframe" src="#" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to use your existing markup would be to simply add rel="external" to your  And your onclick should behave correctly.

```
<a class="link" href="project-url"
    onclick="document.getElementById('project_iframe').src=this.href; 
    return false;" rel="external">
    <h3>title</h3>
</a>

<iframe id="project_iframe" src="#" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> 
</iframe>
```

This will work since jQuery Mobile will treat the link as a normal  tag and return false will simply stop the default action.

---

**Edit** :

Or you can add this to your Js & remove the onclick tag :

```
$('.link').on('touchstart click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('project_iframe').src=this.href; 
    return false;
});
```

here's a fiddle of it : https://jsfiddle.net/onn3a3w0/10/

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the OP is using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: I just put jQuery Mobile CDN in header (css) and footer (js), and add rel="external", but nothing happened.